# Rewrite max using two and statements

Tags: logic

Say I want to rewrite A <= MAX (B, 100) using only AND statements and substractions. <= means smaller or equal. A and B are variables. Is it possible?

I can't seem to use OR's using the Microsoft Solver foundation in this contrived example, which is a simplification of a problem I have at work :

Decision x = new Decision(Domain.Real, "x");
            model.AddDecisions(x);

```
        Decision y = new Decision(Domain.Real, "y");
        model.AddDecisions(y);

        // Add a constraint
        // x <= MAX(y,200);
        model.AddConstraints("zero", x + Math.Sin(44) == 33.2);
        model.AddConstraints("one", y + x == 5);
        model.AddConstraints("three", x <= -y);
        model.AddConstraints("four", x <= 200);
        // Solve the problem
        context.Solve();

        // Display the results 
        Console.WriteLine("x: {0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("y: {0}", y);
```

Comment: It's not, but if the answer is that simple, I'll keep thinking.

Comment: The reason it smells like homework is that the "restriction" seems incredibly arbitrary, not because of how difficult it may or may not be. If you'd justify why that restriction is there, I would likely revise my estimation.

Comment: Did you ask this Q: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=2412

???

Comment: Yep. I don't understand the answer. What is delta?

Comment: For CSP you can do: A <= B | A <= 100
Are you using CSP?

Comment: Can't use CSP since the variables are continuos.

Comment: This "Solver" *does* stink!  Wait for V2.  Seriously...

Comment: Delta is a variable which can be eithr 1 or 0. The trick is that only delta or (1 - delta) can be 1 at any point in time. I am still trying to grasp the answer ... they may be onto something though.

Answer (score 0):

Um, whats wrong with "NOT (A > MAX (B, 100))"?

---

Since MAX is not allowed, then try "NOT (x > a) And NOT (x > 100)".

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what it DOES accept, since that seems to be a very short list.

Comment: AND, plus, minus, multiplication, division, equality, inequality, greater than, smaller than.

Comment: Actually, it's not. It only operates on variables of type boolean, and expressions such as x > a aren't (can't) be converted to boolean.

Comment: Right.  This is ridiculous.  You'd be better off writing your own Rules Engine than spending your time trying to trick something this dysfunctional into working.  And as I have written rules engines myself, I am quite serious about that.

Comment: I think you mean `NOT ((x > a) AND (x > 100))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

- A) Assume that B <= 100, solve for A and B. If A > 100 or B > 100, then this answer is crap.
- B) Assume that B >= 100, solve for A and B. If B < 100, then the answer is crap.
- C) Assert that you A) and B) do not both give the answer.
- D) Write dozens of unit tests (or feed it an XML, etc). If an assert is ever raised, then pause and examine what is going on.

?

Answer (score 0):

Is `B` non-negative?  Then `MAX` is the infinity-norm, since you're allowed multiplication you can approximate this:

```
A*A*A*A*A*A <= B*B*B*B*B*B + 100*100*100*100*100*100
```

If the six-norm isn't a good enough approximation for the infinity-norm, add more terms.

Also, the linked solution can be adapted, and MIP is not even necessary:

```
A <= B + M1
A <= 100 + M2
M1*M2 <= 0
```